# How to write in 2 input at the same time

Tags: php, html, input

Do you have any idea how to write text in two inputs at the same time, what is written in input 1 appears in input 2 but modified for example:
hello do you have any idea how to write text in two inputs at the same time, what is written in input 1 appears in input 2 but modified for example:

Input 1: this is a text

input 2: this-is-a-text

I try to use `str_replace ()` but I can't do it in real time

```
<?php 

$texto = $_POST['title'];
$urlcambiado = str_replace(" ", "-", $texto);

?>

<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: sword-art-online">
<input type="text" name="url_code" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: sword-art-online">
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server. To accomplish what you are trying to do you need to look at using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want using pure javascript:

```js
function URLChange(titlestr) {
  var url=titlestr.replace(/ /g,"-");
  document.getElementsByName("url_code")[0].value=url;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: sword-art-online" onkeyup='URLChange(this.value);'>
<input type="text" name="url_code" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: sword-art-online">
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done on client-side using JavaScript and goes a little bit like this:

**Reference the two input fields**

Both have it's name attribute set to `title` and `url_code` respectively. To get a reference to it we can use the `getElementsByName()` method which returns a HTMLCollection - an array. Since there's just one element for each name we can append a `[0]` to get the first element in the array.
var firstInput=document.getElementsByName("title")[0];
var secondInput=document.getElementsByName("url_code")[0];

**Attach an input event listener**

To find out if the user has typed anything into the first input we need to use this listener which invokes a callback function we can then use to get the actual text.

```
firstInput.addEventListener("input",process);
```

**Modify the text inside the second input**

Inside the callback function we can retrieve the text from the first input, use a regular expression to replace whitespaces by a minus sign and assign the text to the second text field.

```
function process(e) {
  secondInput.value = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '-');
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```js
var firstInput = document.getElementsByName("title")[0];
var secondInput = document.getElementsByName("url_code")[0];

function process(e) {
  secondInput.value = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '-');
}
firstInput.addEventListener("input", process);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: sword-art-online">
<input type="text" name="url_code" class="form-control" placeholder="Ejemplo: sword-art-online">
```